# Python: Windows registry hive access NOT using registry APIs

Tags: python, windows, registry, winreg

I am trying to extract some data out of the Windows registry, both the software hive and ntuser.dat from XP computers.  Currently I'm using `reg.exe` to load the hive and `_winreg` to extract the data.  I need to use `reg.exe` as the computers I'm backing up data from are usually offline and I'm putting the hard drive from them in an external drive bay and loading the hives from that in another Windows session.  It's not feasible to boot up the computers being backed up as they are often failing hard drives or otherwise unbootable.

I've seen a utility called `hivex` which runs under Linux which combines a c-module with a python wrapper to allow for read-only (limited write) access to the Windows registry, without using the Windows Registry APIs.  Sadly there doesn't appear to be a Windows version of `hivex`, assumingly because no one figured a need to access the Windows registry under Windows by directly accessing the hive files.

I'd love to drop the dependency of `reg.exe` being called by `subprocess.Popen()` as calling an external executable has a host of issues, plus it makes the backup utility platform limited.

Does anyone know of a python module which allows for direct access of the hive files themselves?  I already know of, and am currently using `_winreg`, so suggesting that would be less than helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much better it is, but the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) library supplies bindings to most of the windows API.  I don't know the windows API well enough to know if you can open arbitrary hive files, however it could be worth a quick look (the release contains a CHM with the full API mapping).

Comment: Hmm, I think I may be able to use pywin32.  It looks like I can call RegLoadKey from the Win32API with pywin32.  According to the documentation on RegLoadKey, it is able to load the hive at a specific location in HKU or HKLM.  This should be vastly superior to using reg.exe via Popen() to load the hive.  I'd prefer an option that is cross-platform, but I can implement a secondary use of hivex if/when I need to be able to run this program on Linux, so it would use hivex if, say, `import pywin32` throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look to [regobj](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regobj/) it provides pythonic access to registry value (but it is still based on _winreg)

Comment: Yes, my need is to access the hives themselves, directly.  `_winreg` only allows access via the registry API in Windows, which is what `regobj` is based on.  I'm actually using `regobj`, but didn't bother mentioning it, since it is not really any different than using `_winreg` directly, aside from being more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem with calling an external application or using the registry APIs?  If it is the former you can load and unload hives yourself using [RegLoadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724889%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) / [RegUnLoadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724924%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  If it is the latter then I'm sure somebody has written a C library to parse hives directly.  A quick Google search gave me Microsoft's [Offline Registry Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The problem I have right now is I call reg.exe via Popen(), which I don't like doing.  I think I'll go with calling RegLoadKey via pywin32, which I just found out about thanks to Bashwork.  I was really hoping for something like hivex, only cross-platform, so I wouldn't have to implement the same functions twice with different libraries/modules, but I think using pywin32 and hivex both, depending on platform, is so far the best answer I've come across.